# Not able to send tradingview webhook messages to discord using alerts

Tags: json, discord, webhooks, pine-script

I have a tradingview script like this

```
ma200 = sma(close, 200)
ma50 = sma(close, 50)
if crossover(ma50, ma200) or crossover(ma200,ma50)
    alert('{"content":"{{ticker}}, {{interval}}, Market structure change"}', alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

But for some reason the placeholders don't work when sending the message to discord. In discord it appears like this,

[image]

But the same code if I use `alertcondition()` like this,

```
ma200 = sma(close, 200)
ma50 = sma(close, 50)
alertcondition(crossover(ma50, ma200) or crossover(ma200,ma50),title="market structure change",message='{"content":"{{ticker}}, {{interval}}, Market structure change"}')
```

it works perfectly and sends alerts to discord with proper placeholder names.

Why does this happen and how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the {{ }} placeholders will only have functionality in alertcondition(). We need to build our own when using alert().

Try this out as an alternative. These built-ins return a string for the same variables mentioned in the placeholders. Notice how we must add punctuation between built-ins. eg + ','

```
        alert('{"content":"' + syminfo.ticker + ',' + timeframe.period + ', Market structure change"}', alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Cheers and best of luck with your trading and coding

Comment: thank you very much!